# MS-Access Password masks and queries

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a simple form that expects the username and password. It then checks against the database to confirm that the user exists and that the password is correct. If so, it just opens another form. The issue is that when the password field uses a password mark, the query tries to match literally the asterisks...

```
Private Sub cmdAccept_Click()
' Create entry points for the database and the query...
Dim rd As dao.Recordset
Dim sql As String

' Define the query to be performed...
sql = "SELECT [_User], [_Password] FROM tblEmployees WHERE [_User] = '" + frmUser + "'"

' The user pressed the key to log in...
' Check that User and Password aren't empty...

If Len(Me.txtUser) > 0 Then
    ' There is something in the field...
    ' MsgBox ("There is something in the User field...")
    Me.txtUser.SetFocus
    frmUser = Trim(Me.txtUser.Text)
    frmBoolUser = True
Else
    ' Nothing to see here...
    MsgBox ("You need to enter your user name...")
    frmBoolUser = False
End If
    
If Len(Me.txtPassword) > 0 Then
    ' There is something in the field...
    ' Msgbox ("There is something in the Password field...")
    Me.txtPassword.SetFocus
    frmPassword = Trim(Me.txtPassword.Text)
    frmBoolPassword = True
Else
    ' Nothing to see here...
    MsgBox ("You need to enter your password...")
    frmBoolPassword = False
End If

If (frmBoolUser And frmBoolPassword) Then
    ' Both fields have data on them...
    'MsgBox ("The credentials for " + frmUser + " with the password " + frmPassword + " are about to be checked...")
    
    ' MsgBox (sql)
    
    Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(sql)
    
    If rs.EOF Then
        ' We didn't find such user name...
        MsgBox ("No records...")
    Else
        MsgBox ("Yup, the user name exists!")
        ' Thus, we need to check if the provided password is the correct one...
        ' MsgBox (frmPassword)
        ' MsgBox (rs.[_Password])
        If (rs.[_Password]) = (frmPassword) Then
            ' The password is correct...
            ' MsgBox ("You're awesome!")
            DoCmd.OpenForm "frmMenu"
            
        Else
            ' The password is incorrect...'
            MsgBox ("Well, that didn't work, did it?")
        End If
    End If
End If
```

End Sub

So the problem is here:

If (rs.[_Password]) = (frmPassword) Then...

Say password is 12345. Thus, frmPassword contains *****, which is different than what the field Password contains, which is 12345.

I'm surely missing something here, as having a password mask that cannot be read within the system is absurd.

Any help would greatly appreciated!

Comment: The code works as expected as long as you don't use the password mask in the password field, I migh add.

Comment: Don't use `.Text`, use `.Value`.

Comment: The comment of @Andre is the answer.

Comment: Yup. Andre answer solves this issue. Thank you!